# Inner Product Spaces, suggestion for book.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, inner-products

Can you suggest me name of some books which would help me visualize IPS better? Like, books having diagrams and stuff?

Answer (score 2):

I like **Linear Algebra Done Right** by Sheldon Axler.

Comment: The chapters on Inner-Product Spaces and Operators on Inner-Product Spaces are freely available at http://linear.axler.net.

Answer (score 2):

Although severely lacking in diagrams, *Istrăţescu V.I - Inner Product Structures: Theory and Applications* has alot of useful and interesting information about inner products and inner product spaces.

Answer (score 1):

[**Tensor Geometry: The Geometric Viewpoint and its Uses**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/354052018X) by Dodson/Poston has a lot of pictures and diagrams.